# How do I query the text of an element (Component) using WicketTester?

Tags: java, testing, wicket, wicket-tester

Rather than specifying the id-path for components to click in WicketTester I'd like to find the link with a specific text.

I can use `MarkupContainer.visitChildren` to run through the tree, but can I get the actual rendered component text for each leaf - something like `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see TagTester. It is part of WicketTester family.